# ExtJs Binding with convertors (formulas)

Tags: javascript, extjs, data-binding, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I whant to use in binding if it is possible something like WPF convertors. In ExtJs examples I see three types:

1. "{field}"
2. "Hello {field}"
3. "{!field}"

This example is work fine.

```
   Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {
                xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                width: 50,
                align: 'left',
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    bind: {
                        text: "{record.Text}",
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    });
```

But I need more. On fly change somethig or calculate. For example change style of the label depending some information from the record or fomatting and combining infomation from many fields. I want somethink like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {
                xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                width: 50,
                align: 'left',
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    bind: {
                        text: "{calculateText(record)}",
                        style: {
                            color: "{calculateColor(record)}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    });
```

I read about formulas and I try:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {
                xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                width: 50,
                align: 'left',
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    viewModel:{
                        formulas: {
                            myText: function(get){
                                return get('record').Text + '$';
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    bind: {
                        text: "{myText}",

                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    });
```

and this

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {
                xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                width: 50,
                align: 'left',
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    viewModel:{
                        formulas: {
                            myText: {
                                bind: {
                                    text: "{record.Text}",                                    
                                },
                                get: function(data){
                                    return data.text + '$';
                                },

                            },
                        }
                    },
                    bind: {
                        text: "{myText}",

                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    });
```

But when I try to add my ViewModel to current context - parent ViewModel with "record" is loose and not working.
What I do wrong and how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I resolve my problem using rowViewModel config. Example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        rowViewModel: {
            formulas: {
                myText: function(get){
                    return get('record.Text') + '$';
                },
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                width: 50,
                align: 'left',
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'label',                        
                    bind: {
                        text: "{myText}",

                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parent viewmodel as part of a viewmodel config.

```
viewModel:{
    parent: this.getViewModel(),
    formulas: {
        myText: {
            bind: {
                text: "{record.Text}",                                    
            },
            get: function(data){
                return data.text + '$';
            }
        }
    }
}
```